# Clarification of this Taylor approximation

Tags: taylor-expansion

I've been stuck with how this Taylor expansion works,

$$f(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{x^2+1}\right)$$

So for me the expansion when $x\to\infty$ is (by using the known expansion of $\ln(1+x),x\to0 $)

$$\ln(1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\ldots, \quad x\to0.$$

So since I have that $\frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{x^2+1} \to0$ for $x\to \infty$ and $\frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{x^2+1} \to\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}(1+o(1))$
I've just inserted $\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ in the logarithmic expansion
$$\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{1}{2x^{3}}$$

plus it's residue, however when I try to confirm it in mathemathica I get

$$1+\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\frac{2}{x^{2}} + O\!\left(\frac{1}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}\right)$$

And I don't understand where the $x^2$ comes from.

Comment: Your computation is wrong, Mathematica's answer is right.  You will have to show more steps of your computation if you want anyone to find your mistake.

Comment: The $\frac{2}{x^2}$ comes from the $2$ in the numerator of the quotient and the $x^2$ in the denominator

Comment: You should not have the $1$ in the expansions as the limit at $\infty$ is $0$

Comment: @GEdgar this was my thinking process, did it help a bit or am i just too lost for help?

Comment: You need more terms than your $\frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{x^2+1} \to\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}(1+o(1))$

Comment: @Henry, thanks for answering, can i ask why would i need more terms? and how can i realize how many terms i need?

Comment: You apparently want terms up to $\frac1{x^3}$, so it might be an idea to go at least this far for each of your series approximations

Answer (score 1):

Hint (almost solution).

$$f(x)=\ln(x^2+\sqrt{x}+3) - \ln(1+x^2) = \ln 3 + \ln\Big(1 + \frac{x^2+\sqrt{x}}{3}\Big) -  \ln(1+x^2) $$

Further $\ln(1+x^2) = \ln((1+t) = t - \frac{t^2}2 - \frac{t^3}3 + \ldots $ where $t = x^2$. So
$$ \ln(1+x^2) = x^2 - \frac{x^4}2 + o(x^4).$$

Put $u = \sqrt{x}$, $v = \frac{u^4 + u}{3}$. Hence
$$ \ln\Big(1 + \frac{x^2+\sqrt{x}}{3}\Big)   = \ln (1 + v) = v -\frac{v^2}2 - \frac{v^3}3 + o(v^3)$$ $$
= \frac{u^4 + u}{3} - \frac12 \Big( \frac{u^4 + u}{3} \Big)^2 + \frac13 \Big( \frac{u^4 + u}{3} \Big)^3 + o(u^3)$$ $$= \frac{u^4 + u}{3} - \frac12 \Big( \frac{u^4 + u}{3} \Big)^2 + \frac13 \Big( \frac{u^4 + u}{3} \Big)^3 + o(x^{\frac32}),$$
where $u = \sqrt{x}$. Hence we may get Taylor expansion of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

One of my professor used to claim : *"We are always be closer to zero than to infinity"*

So, for $$f(x)=\log \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{x^2+1}\right)$$
start letting $x=\frac{1}{t^2}$ to make
$$f(t)=\log \left(3+\frac{t^3-2}{t^4+1}\right)=\log(1+t^3+3 t^4)-\log(1+t^4)$$

Now, it is quite simple. When done for $t$, go back to $x$.